# Renaming a group of files in PHP

Tags: php

My file located in domain.com/work.php is as follows:

```
<?php
for ($x = 2; $x <= 30; $x++) {
    $old = "gfx/dc/10/" . str_pad($x, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ".jpg";
    $new = "gfx/dc/10/" . str_pad(($x - 1), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ".jpg";
    rename($old, $new);
}
```

The folder containing the files is domain.com/gfx/dc/10/002.jpg 003, 004, etc. None of the file names are changed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no question here...

Comment: @AlexHowansky err .. the question is what am I doing wrong, none of the file names are changed, but for some odd reason stack overflow was saying that the wording wasn't up to their standards. Sorry about that.

Comment: Check the return value of the `rename()` call, it's likely false. I'll wager the source file doesn't exist or you don't have write permission to it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to check the return value? As for the file existence, I can open the picture using the url just fine, it exists. As for the permissions, I just tried changing them to 777 and rerunning the script. Still no change to the files.

Comment: `$result = rename($old, $new); var_dump($result);`

Comment: You're right, it's returning false.

Comment: Actually, @AlexHowansky was right, it was a permissions problem. I ended up having to change the permission of the folder containing the files.